# Solana Frontend phantom wallet integration issue for making the transactions on the devnet

Tags: transactions, solana, wallet-connect, solana-program-library, solana-transaction-instruction

We working for a dex based solution on solana network, it properly works on localnet including all the trasanctions like Add and Remove liquidity etc.
But we make changes to devnet/testnet remaining all same but encountering the following issues. Please let me know, whether devnet has any issues or any other solutions needed to resolve this case.

[Solana devnet initialize code with phantom wallet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTFhk.png)

[Solana localnet initialize code with wallet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6Ye8.png)

[Instructions error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJIq6.png)

Kindly suggest me the better solution to proceed further.

We are trying to work on the Solana Devnet with a connection to the Phantom wallet using the above-mentioned code on the snap.

We expect to find a solution regarding the changes that need to be made on our end to work on Devnet, considering that all the functions mentioned above are currently working fine in Solana localnet.